# Why would a ts-node compile error be seemingly caused by the style of dependency declaration

Tags: node.js, ts-node

I've been developing a node package using typescript (let's call it "package T") in tandem with a co-worker who is developing a javascript node package ("package J"). Both packages are in their own private bitbucket repository. Package J is a dependency of package T, and has a .d.ts file used to expose some exported functions that package T needs.

For a while, I've been cloning package J from bitbucket onto my computer locally, and marking the dependency in package T's package.json file like this:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "packageJ": "file:/complete/path/to/package_J",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

This has always worked and behaved as expected, so I never thought anything of it. No issues. No errors

Recently I modified the dependency declaration to reference the code in bitbucket directly as follows:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "packageJ": "git@bitbucket.org:repository/name/containing/package_J.git",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Now after that change, *and that change alone*, I'm seeing the following error when running:

```
/does_not_matter/packageT/node_modules/packageJ/somefile.js:1
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

somefile.js is the file that has a corresponding somefile.d.ts file. The .d.ts file looks like this:

```
declare module 'packageJ/src/somefile' {
    export function someFunctionINeed(args: string): JSX.Element;
}
```

The import looks like this:

```
import { someFunctionINeed } from 'packageJ/src/somefile';
```

I have already tried many different recommended changes to my package.json and tsconfig.json in order to resolve this (e.g. modifying the module, target, esModuleInterop, etc.).

I have verified that the local copy of the code is identical to what's in bitbucket. I have even verified that the code in node_modules is the same after running npm install regardless of how the dependency defined in the package.json.

Is there anything I can do to allow the code to run with the dependency pointed to bitbucket, or am I forever tied to maintaining a local copy of my coworkers repository?

Why would the style of dependency declaration change the behavior of the Typescript compiler?

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried that. Not only does it not help, it breaks a bunch of other things.

Keep in mind that the issue isn't in my code, but in one of my dependencies under /node_modules/

Also note that the code *does* work properly, but only when the dependency is reverenced as a local directory. It only fails the ts-node compile checks when the dependency is given as a remote repository.

Comment: I noticed just now that when the dependency is referenced as a file, a soft link is created to the package directory instead of being literally copied into the node_modules directory. 

I just tried leaving the git@bitbucket.org-style dependency in place, but replacing the directory under node_modules with a soft link, and the issue does not appear. I also diffed the code between the two, and they are identical, so it seams that ts-node just doesn't throw errors when the dependency is a soft link.

I already have the skipLibCheck property set to true, and that didn't help anything.

Comment: Using the "exclude" array in the tsconfig.json also doesn't help. I specified ```"exclude": ["node_modules/**/*"]``` just to be overzealous, and I'm still seeing the same ts-node compile error.